# Ввод с кнопки только одной запятой(калькулятор) wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть объект textblock в который помещаются значения, которые заданы кнопкам, пример

```
    private void btn_9_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tb1.Text += "9";
    }

    private void btn_null_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tb1.Text += "0";
    }

    private void btn_dot_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tb1.Text.Length == 0)
            return;
        else
        tb1.Text += ",";          
    }
```

Как разрешить ввод только одной запятой? Чтобы нельзя было сделать например такой ввод для нецелого числа 5,656,,,56,567567,, .
С запретом ввода запятой до чисел я проблему решил, а вот на ввод конкретно с кнопки одной запятой не знаю как сделать, еще раз повторю **!!не с клавиатуры!!**

Comment: Как вариант можно просто блокировать кнопку после ввода запятой, и разблокировать ее после нажатия кнопки арифметического действия, но хотелось бы узнать, как разрешить ввод только одной запятой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем-то, довольно просто: достаточно проверять содержит ли строка запятую. Примерно так:

```
if (!tb1.Text.Contains(","))
    tb1.Text += ",";
```

Как несложно догадаться, в этом случае запятая будет добавлена к строке только если её там ещё нет.

Comment: Все равно добавляется

Comment: Так, все сделал. Спасибо

Comment: Решение предложенное @SOFL в комментариях лучше.

Comment: @FoggyFinder (1) Почему? (2) В этом же комментарии он просит другое решение.

Comment: На самом деле, вот так сделал, сочетая мой способ и предложенный здесь, спасибо кстати за супер метод Contains.

Comment: if (tb1.Text.Contains(","))
            {
                btn_dot.IsEnabled = false;
            }

Comment: Ну, как раз в этом случае правильней блокировать кнопку после первого добавления запятой, без проверки - кнопка-то всё равно заблокируется. Другое дело, что при стирании запятой кнопку нужно разблокировать. То есть это уже два действия вместо одной проверки.

Comment: @eastwing 1. Это `WPF`, а не `WinForms` - лучше работать через привязки данных. 2. С точки зрения логики можно ввести всего одну `,` следовательно тут нужно либо блокировать кнопку (визуальное отображение) либо поставить валидацию и выводить информационное сообщение об ошибке. Вы же предлагаете просто игнорировать без уведомлений о причинах.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Просто откройте любой калькулятор, и посмотрите, как там работает эта кнопка. Можете приложить скриншоты сообщений об ошибках при попытке повторно ввести запятую.

Comment: @eastwing как-то не пользуюсь подобными калькуляторами. Открыл стандартный из Windows... - действует как вы описали. Мою точку зрения это не изменит, вашу, как понимаю, тоже. Зачем тогда спорить?

Comment: Незачем, согласен